# ChartJS chart is bugged after adding new data

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

Actually in my website i build a char with some data from MySQL Database.

Every time the chart button is pressed a modal will appear an AJAX call will be sent to the server and then the Chart will be drawn.

The issue is that after adding new data to database and by opening the modal with the ChartJS by moving the mouse the ChartJS tilt between chart with new data and the old one.

[image]

Here is the code

```
var chart;

$(function () {
    renderChart();
});


function renderChart() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('barchart').getContext('2d');
    var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 400);
    gradient.addColorStop(0, '#007AFD');
    gradient.addColorStop(1, '#00B1FF');
    var options = {
        legend: false,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        tooltips: {
            displayColors: false
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                gridLines: {
                    display: false,
                },
                barPercentage: 0.3,
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    stacked: true,
                    stepSize: 1,
                    beginAtZero: true,
                },
                gridLines: {
                    borderDash: [5, 15],
                    drawBorder: false
                }
            }]
        }
    };
    chart = new Chart(ctx, { type: 'bar', labels: [], data: [] });
}

function loadReports(data) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/getReports",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({ data: data }),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (r) {
            data = r.d;
            if (data != '[]') {
                data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                chart.data.labels = data.map(ora => ora.ORARIO);
                chart.data.datasets[0].data[0] = data.map(cop => cop.COPERTI);
                chart.update();
            } else {
                chart.data.labels = [];
                chart.data.datasets[0].data = [];
                chart.update();
            }

        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error.responseText);
        }
    });

}
```

buildChart() is called on load and chart is declared on top of JS file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you drawing a new chart by clicking on the button?
You should draw your chart just 1 time and then update the data:

```
function addData(chart, label, data) {
chart.data.labels.push(label);
chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
    dataset.data.push(data);
  });
  chart.update();
}

function removeData(chart) {
    chart.data.labels.pop();
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data.pop();
    });
    chart.update();
}
```

Docs: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html

you can try it with this code:

```
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "Default.aspx/getReports",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  data: JSON.stringify({ data: data }),
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(r) {
    data = r.d;
    if (data != "[]") {
      data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
      chart.data.labels = data.map(ora => ora.ORARIO);
      chart.data.datasets[0].data = data.map(coperti => coperti.COPERTI);
      chart.update();
    } else {
      chart.data.labels = [];
      chart.data.datasets[0].data = [];
      chart.update();
    }
    $("#modalChart").modal("show");
  },
  error: function(error) {
    alert(error.responseText);
  }
});
```

Comment: Oh yes actually i draw the chart every time the button is pressed, could you explain how can i integrate those function inside AJAX? and actually in chart should i pass ctx or the chart object?

Comment: yea , what is data = r.d whats that r.d? object, array, number, string?

Comment: data = r.d is an array and by using map as you can see from the code i get each item from that array

Comment: actually i get here https://imgur.com/NmBcn1M 'Cannot set property 'data' of undefined'

Comment: Maybe coperti is empty

Comment: no actually for each ORARIO there is a COPERTI https://imgur.com/skTT5fY

Comment: https://imgur.com/E5KSJi9 even by evaluating data.map the cop.COPERTI are all  in

Comment: Show me where u initialize ur chart

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200610/discussion-between-igor-mytyuk-and-ifaruki).